# Core-js, how to include only needed polyfills

Tags: javascript, reactjs, phpstorm, core-js

Is there any way to include only needed core-js polyfills?

For example I want include only `core-js/features/promise` and I don't want to include whole library 'core-js'.

I am using PhpStorm. May be any helpers or plugins exist to analyze the code and say what polyfills I need to include?

Answer (score 0):

Sure! It's called [babel.js](https://babeljs.io/) and if you correctly configure it, it will work exactly as you explain. You can find documentation [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration).

Comment: can you explain how to do it?

Comment: @denismart I don't know your existing setup. Generally you would need a build tool (like webpack or gulp). Depending on your requirements, you can configure it one way or another. [Here](https://github.com/Uzwername/base-react-webpack-config) is a config that I use. Among other things, it uses babel. You may find its config in `webpack.prod.js`.